# zendframework2 layout of my custom module overrides the default when an occurs 404 and other exception

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I followed the directions in this discussion

[Use differents layouts to differents modules zend framework 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351034/use-differents-layouts-to-differents-modules-zend-framework-2) (kta Answered March 29 at 13:18)

to be able to have two different layouts in two different modules of an application ZF2

Everything works fine but I have a problem with the error pages and in particular 404

First load the application module (the default skeleton of the application) and then later the my custom module.

In the configuration file of the admin module I excluded references errors template in order to view those below the application module.

The problem is that when the error is detected is used the layout of the my custom module rather than in the application module.

can anyone help me?

module.config.php (admin module)

```
'view_manager' => array(
    'display_not_found_reason' => true,
    'display_exceptions' => true,
    'doctype' => 'HTML5',
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        'admin' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
    'template_map' => array(
        'Admin/layout' => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
        'admin/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/admin/index/mail.phtml',
        .....
    ),
),
```

module.config.php (application)

```
   'view_manager' => array(
    'display_not_found_reason' => true,
    'display_exceptions' => true,
    'doctype' => 'HTML5',
    'not_found_template' => 'error/404',
    'exception_template' => 'error/index',
    'template_map' => array(
        'Application/layout' => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
        'application/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/index/index.phtml',
        'error/404' => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
        'error/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
        'application/index/mail' => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/index/mail.phtml',
        'application/index/curriculumPartial' => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/index/curriculumPartial.phtml',
        'application/index/mail_admin' => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/index/mail_admin.phtml'
    ),
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        __DIR__ . '/../view',

    ),
),
```

application module

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
    $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
    $sm = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
    $eventManager->getSharedManager()->attach('*', MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR, array($this, 'onDispatchError'), 100);
}

public function onDispatchError(MvcEvent $event){
    $response = $event->getResponse();
    if ($response->getStatusCode() == 404) {
        $url = $event->getRouter()->assemble(array(), array('name' => 'error'));
        $requestUri = $event->getRequest()->getRequestUri();
        $ViewModel = $event->getViewModel();
        //$response->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Location', "$url?url=$requestUri");
        $response->setStatusCode(200);
        $response->sendHeaders();
        $event->stopPropagation(true);
    } elseif($response->getStatusCode() == 500){
        //DO SOMETHING else?
        return;
    }
}
```

admin module

```
public function onBootstrap($e)
{
    $e->getApplication()->getEventManager()->getSharedManager()->attach('Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController', 'dispatch', function($e) {
        $controller = $e->getTarget();
        $controllerClass = get_class($controller);
        $moduleNamespace = substr($controllerClass, 0, strpos($controllerClass, '\\'));
        $controller->layout($moduleNamespace . '/layout');
    }, 100);
}
```

I think the problem comes from the fact that the application module is loaded before the module admin. In fact, finding no route in the application form, the control is passed to the module admin. at that point is set a new template which are then rendered error pages.

Comment: You'll need to post an example, a demo, or at least some code if you expect an answer. I don't think there is enough information in your OP to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by reversing the order of the load module but would like to know if there is a cleaner way to do it.