# ZF2- Rendering custom 404 error page

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have multiple modules in a ZF2 Application. I want each module to have its own 404 error page. I noticed that there is a `not_found_template` key in module.config.php, where I can set to an error phtml. But when ZF2 caching is enabled, each module over writes this key value.

So, I tried to come up with the following code in the `onBootStrap` function of Module.php of each module. This code attempts to catch the 404 error, switches the layout for that module and renders the page properly.
The following code works till the returning of the ViewModel part, but the code still tries to look for a not_found_template key. Can any one help fixing this piece of code, so it renders the 404 properly?

```
   $eventManager   = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $serviceManager = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();

    $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR, function(MvcEvent $event) 
                          use ($serviceManager )
    {
        $response = $event->getResponse();
        if ($response->getStatusCode() == "404")
        {
            $viewModel = new \Zend\View\Model\ViewModel(array(
            'message' => 'Page not found',
            'reason' => 'error-occurred',
            'exception' => 'Page not found - 404',
            ));

            $request = $event->getRequest();
            $response = $event->getResponse();

            //Render AJAX error view if it's an AJAX Request, 
            //else render normal error view.
            if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
                $viewModel->setTerminal(true);
                $viewModel->setTemplate('error/404-ajax.phtml');
            }
            else
            {
                $viewModel->setTemplate('error/404.phtml');
            }
            $event->getViewModel()->addChild($viewModel);
            $event->stopPropagation();
            $response->setStatusCode(200);
            return $viewModel;
        }
    }, -100);
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi, do you find a solution to render one 404 error page per module?

Comment: @ceadreak http://stackoverflow.com/a/17896811/1146562