# Specific Layout for error page in ZF2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm learning ZF2 and I am constructing a web site to make sure that I understand the new concepts of ZF2, but I was wondering if there is a way to specify a template for the error pages in the application module.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There some pre-set configuration options within the `module.config.php` like:

```
...
'view_manager' => array(
   'not_found_template' => 'error/404',
   'exception_template' => 'error/exception',
   'template_map' => array(
      'error/404'       => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
      'error/exception' => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/exception.phtml',
   ),
),
...
```

After creating the Folder and the Files you should be good to go.

Comment: Yes, I did already that, but how can I add a diferent layout for only this pages?

Comment: theres a pretty good blog entry here: http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2014/01/01/zend-framework-2-programmatically-handle-404-page/. You'll only have to change the layout regarding the current error like so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351034/use-differents-layouts-to-differents-modules-zend-framework-2